# How to don't show Firebase notification when the application in Foreground on Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm developing a chat application, I use `Firebase` for push notification.

In `Background` and `Foreground`, Method `DidReceiveRemoteNotification()` work well.

But when the application in `Foreground`, I don't want to show `Firebase notification` because It annoys the user. I just want to handle the event when the application receives `Firebase notification` and don't show `Firebase notification`.

[image: Firebase_push_notification]

I tried removing 2 params `alert-title` and `alert-body` on config of `Firebase`:

**First**: `http://{url}/demo?device-token={token}&alert-title={title}&alert-body={body}`

**Later**: `http://{url}/demo?device-token={token}`

After changing `Firebase` config, I can't push `Firebase notification` when the application turns off.

So, I must use `First` config.

=> How to don't show `Firebase notification` when the application in `Foreground` on `Xamarin iOS`?

This is my code:

```
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        try
        {
            // App in Foreground
            if (!_isInBackground)
            {
                // Foreground
                if (userInfo?.ContainsKey(new NSString("payload")) == true)
                {
                    // TODO: handle Foreground
                    return;
                }
            }

            // App in Background
            // Checking push notification message
            if (userInfo?.ContainsKey(new NSString("payload")) == true)
            {
                var payload = userInfo[new NSString("payload")]?.ToString();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload))
                {
                    // TODO: handle Background

                }

                // Push notification message
                PushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);

                // Inform system of fetch results
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Please help me!

Comment: Hi , could you show the code of `AppDelegate.cs` in Xamrain.ios , this can be realized from there .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From FCM [document about receiving message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive) ,

> In iOS 10 and above, you can set the [UNUserNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649522-delegate?language=objc) delegate to receive display notifications from Apple and FIRMessaging's delegate property to receive data messages from FCM. If you do not set these two delegates with AppDelegate, method swizzling for message handling is disabled. You'll need to call [appDidReceiveMessage:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/FIRMessaging#a23555ac1d3fd956b56c41b1a9de5122d) to track message delivery and analytics.

```
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  // [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

  // Print message ID.
  if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
  }

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

  // Change this to your preferred presentation option
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}
```

So you can change what to show (Or no alert) when meeage receive while app is in the foreground.If `completionHandler` set `UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone` then there will no alert. You can have a try with this way.

> [UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationpresentationoptionnone?language=objc) : No alert.

Comment: but method `DidReceiveRemoteNotification()` pass to parameter is
`Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler`. So, I can't set `completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);`

Comment: @HuuBaoNguyen Okey , could you show the `AppDelegate.cs` file , I will check it.

Comment: method `DidReceiveRemoteNotification()` is contained in `AppDelegate.cs` file.

Comment: @HuuBaoNguyen Then show content of `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` , I will check it .

Comment: I updated my code on my question... Please check it! Thanks!

Comment: @HuuBaoNguyen Thanks for updating. `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` is no problem, do you have a try [set the priority of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message). In ios , you can set [apns-priority](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1) be 5 to have a try.

Comment: We will set `apns-priority` on Xamarin iOS, how?

Comment: @HuuBaoNguyen This need use json style data to push notification .https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image

Comment: I'm using [node-pushnotifications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifications) for push notification. It is the same with push notification of  `Firebase`. At [APN](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifications#apn), I set `priority` `5` (normal) but `user notification` stills appear.

Comment: @HuuBaoNguyen The another solution is do something in `userNotificationCenter`  my answer shows that .`completionHandler` set `UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone`

Comment: @ Junior Jiang - MSFT, but in `AppDelegate.cs` of `Xamarin iOS`, I can't set `UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone` anywhere. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @HuuBaoNguyen First, could you invoke `userNotificationCenter` this method in `AppDelegate.cs` ? If not you can not set it. And here is a article about [silent notifications](https://medium.com/fenrir-inc/handling-ios-push-notifications-the-not-so-apparent-side-420891ddf10b) for reference.

Comment: I still can't turn Notification Firebase off with URL `http://{url}/demo?device-token={token}&alert-title={title}&alert-body={body}` .... @Junior Jiang - MSFT

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to show / hide notification when application is in foreground is to set UNNotificationPresentationOptions in AppDelegate FinishLaunching method.

By default when app is in foreground, UNNotificationPresentationOptions is set to None, causing notification to not show up when application is not in foreground. But for your case it seems that it is set to value other then None.

UNNotificationPresentationOptions is defined as

```
public enum UNNotificationPresentationOptions
{
    Alert,  //Display the notification as an alert, using the notification text.
    Badge,  //Display the notification badge value in the application's badge.
    None,   //No options are set.
    Sound  //Play the notification sound.
}
```

//To set for alert

```
FirebasePushNotificationManager.CurrentNotificationPresentationOption = UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert;
```

//You can also combine them

```
FirebasePushNotificationManager.CurrentNotificationPresentationOption = UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Badge;
```

**Reference:** https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/6